# Error when using landscape evolution model CHILD (Channel-Hillslope Integrated Landscape Development)

Tags: c++, matlab, landscape

I tried to simulate a strike-slip earthquake with a short but rapid strike-slip event using CHILD model. I created a 1000-m * 1000-m grid with 5-m resolution. First I generated an original stream (see the figure). Then I set a strike-slip event. The runtime is 10 year and slip rate is 500 mm/yr when uprate and other parameters like KB are zero because I want to use this way to simulate an instant strike-slip event which creat about 5-m offset. The faultopt is 100-m. But when I ran the .in file, the problem "Element #237518 is not active but within the active part of the edge list. Error in mesh consistency" arised. I don't know whether CHILD doesn't support that method? Or other reasons there.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4Qmy.png)

I tried to solve this problem by adjusting the seed. But a new problem "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" appears and no other error messages, whic confused me again. And different seeds brought different errors, which makes me to think aboout whether CHILD doesn't permit such instant and large slip just like what I did.
If there's someone ever used CHILD model and could give me some advice, I'd appreciate it very much. That will help me a lot.

Comment: the reason for the segfault is in your code and can only be fixed by looking at your code. Please read about [mcve]